# Image Hosting On Apache Tomcat

Tags: html, eclipse, tomcat

Okay, so I am new to Web Development and I just started out with HTML, CSS, Servlets, JSPs and all the good stuff.I am using Eclipse Mars along with Apache Tomcat 8 as my web server.Tomcat is properly set up, as I have done other projects on Eclipse and run them on the server previously with no problems.

I created a simple form shown below which just accepts user name and stream, validates the data in a servlet using JDBC and forwards to a JSP which then displays a corresponding message ( user found/ not found), along with an image(success/failure).

HTML CODE->

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Student Login</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: antiquewhite;
            font-family: Calibri;
            padding: 150px 150px 150px 150px;
        }
        
        h1 {
            border: 2px dotted black;
            margin-left: 30%;
            margin-right: 30%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 align="center">Just For Fun</h1>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <form action="Serve" method="post">
        <p align="center">First Name
            <input type="text" name="fname">
            <br> </p>
        <p align="center">Last Name
            <input type="text" name="lname">
            <br> </p>
        <p align="center">Stream
            <select name="stream" size="1">
                <option value="AEIE">Applied Electronics And Instrumentation Engineering</option>
                <option value="CSE">Computer Science And Engineering</option>
                <option value="ECE">Electronics And Communications Engineering</option>
                <option value="EE">Electrical Engineering</option>
                <option value="ME">Mechanical Engineering</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p align="center">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"> </p>
        <hr> </form>
    <p align="justify"> <img src="Images/success.png"> <img src="Images/fail.png"> </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Now this is the index page, where I have intentionally displayed two images just for debigging purposes.
If I right click on this page and select "Show In Web Browser" on Eclipse, both the images show up just fine, but if I run the project on the Server, somehow only the "fail.png" shows up, and the "success.png" is broken.
Now both the files are residing on the same folder, so I know that it's not a path issue.

#### Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: Did you verify lower/upper case to be consistent?

Comment: Yes that is the exact file name :/

Comment: Do I have to change any settings on Eclipse for it to include the image files on the server when the project is run ?

Comment: Upper/lower case could be an issue, if developping on Windows and serving from, e.g., Linux. **Success.png** or **success.PNG** would work with your source file on Windows but not on Linux. - How about entering the image URL manually in your browser? Does this work?

Comment: Well when I ran it, I tried typing in this http://localhost:8080/Show/Images/fail.png, which works, but the same for succes2s.png gave a 404 error

Comment: Looks like the success Image is *not* in the right place. (I suspect the **2** in your most recent comment is a typo.)

Comment: yeah sorry, that'd be success.png

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that fail.png get displayed, success.png must also get displayed. Check if it not naming or extension issue, i.e may be file extension is different other than png, or there can be naming difference. If in case fail.png is also not working then ensure that Images folder lies in Tomcat Working space directory.

Comment: I don't know about Tomcat Working Directory as I am doing this on Eclipse.
The images are located in Show/WebContent/Images, and the html file resides in Show/WebContent, so the relative path is correct right ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved.
I didn't change any code, neither did i reinstall the server, it just started working by itself.

#### Looks like Tomcat just randomly serves images it wants and 404s the ones it doesn't want :P